# Efficiently comparing data across rows in a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a `CSV` file of monthly cell phone bills in no particular order that I read into a `Pandas` `Dataframe`. I'd like to add a column for each bill that shows how much it differed from the previous bill for the same account. This CSV is just a sub-set of my data. My code works fine, but is pretty sloppy and very slow when you look at a CSV file close to a million rows.

What should I be doing to make this more efficient?

CSV:

```
Account Number,Bill Month,Bill Amount
4543,3/1/2015,300
4543,1/1/2015,100
4543,2/1/2015,200
2322,1/1/2015,22
2322,3/1/2015,38
2322,2/1/2015,25
```

Python:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('data.csv', low_memory=False)

# sort my data and reset the index so I can use index and index - 1 in the loop
data = data.sort_values(by=['Account Number', 'Bill Month'])
data = data.reset_index(drop=True)

# add a blank column for the difference
data['Difference'] = np.nan

for index, row in data.iterrows():

    # special handling for the first row so I don't get negative indexes
    if index == 0:
         data.ix[index, 'Difference'] = "-"
    else:
        # if the account in the current row and the row before are the same, then compare Bill Amounts
        if data.ix[index, 'Account Number'] == data.ix[index - 1, 'Account Number']:
            data.ix[index, 'Difference'] = data.ix[index, 'Bill Amount'] - data.ix[index - 1, 'Bill Amount']
        else:
           data.ix[index, 'Difference'] = "-"

print data
```

Desired Output:

```
   Account Number Bill Month  Bill Amount Difference
0            2322   1/1/2015           22          -
1            2322   2/1/2015           25          3
2            2322   3/1/2015           38         13
3            4543   1/1/2015          100          -
4            4543   2/1/2015          200        100
5            4543   3/1/2015          300        100
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
In [37]: df = df.sort_values(['Account Number','Bill Month'])

In [38]: df['Difference'] = (df.groupby(['Account Number'])['Bill Amount']
   ....:                       .diff()
   ....:                       .fillna('-')
   ....:                    )

In [39]: df
Out[39]:
   Account Number Bill Month  Bill Amount Difference
3            2322 2015-01-01           22          -
5            2322 2015-02-01           25          3
4            2322 2015-03-01           38         13
1            4543 2015-01-01          100          -
2            4543 2015-02-01          200        100
0            4543 2015-03-01          300        100
```

Explanation:

`diff()` will be applied to each group separately - it'll return the difference between the "next" value and the current value:

```
In [123]: df.groupby(['Account Number'])['Bill Amount'].diff()
Out[123]:
3      NaN
5      3.0
4     13.0
1      NaN
2    100.0
0    100.0
dtype: float64
```

`fillna('-')` - fills all NaN's with the specified value: `-`:

```
In [124]: df.groupby(['Account Number'])['Bill Amount'].diff().fillna('-')
Out[124]:
3      -
5      3
4     13
1      -
2    100
0    100
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks, this is so clean! Can you add a quick explanation of how the `df.diff()` knows which values values to subtract and when to apply `fillna()`

Comment: @user2242044, i've added an explanation to my answer - please check

Comment: Thanks for the expalantion

Comment: actually one more quick clarification. Is there a way to do a little more complex than just the difference (such as `.diff()/2`)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111018/discussion-between-user2242044-and-maxu).

Answer (score 1):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Account Number': {0: 4543, 1: 4543, 2: 4543, 3: 2322, 4: 2322, 5: 2322},
    'Bill Amount': {0: 300.0, 1: 100.0, 2: 200.0, 3: 22.0, 4: 38.0, 5: 25.0},
    'Bill Month': {
        0: pd.Timestamp('2015-03-01 00:00:00'),
        1: pd.Timestamp('2015-01-01 00:00:00'),
        2: pd.Timestamp('2015-02-01 00:00:00'),
        3: pd.Timestamp('2015-01-01 00:00:00'),
        4: pd.Timestamp('2015-03-01 00:00:00'),
        5: pd.Timestamp('2015-02-01 00:00:00')}}
```

You can group on account number and billing month (which sorts by default), sum the Bill Amount (or just take the first if you are guaranteed to only have one bill per month), group again on the first level of the index (the account number), and take the difference using `diff`.

```
>>> (df.groupby(['Account Number', 'Bill Month'])['Bill Amount']
       .sum()
       .groupby(level=0)
       .diff())
Account Number  Bill Month
2322            2015-01-01    NaN
                2015-02-01      3
                2015-03-01     13
4543            2015-01-01    NaN
                2015-02-01    100
                2015-03-01    100
```

Comment: Thanks, this is great. In this example, is Account Number now the index column?

Comment: Both Account Number and Bill Month.